# Return in function without return value in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Let's take a look at this function:

```
func nothing(){
    return
}
```

it does not return a value, but we can write `return` statement how Swift handle that ? what happens behind the scene does `return` without value returns 0 or any value to handle this case ?

Comment: There is no `if`. `return` returns from the `selectItem` function (which has no return value).

Comment: Yes, I know, but what happens behind the scene, how Swift deal with that, how it's implemented in the language

Comment: `return` in the else-block is like any other `return` from the function. If the function has a return value then you must return a value in the else-case of guard as well.

Comment: @MartinR but we can return in the function it self, my example was misleading, question updated

Comment: As @zneak said, it just means "return control to the caller". (However, in Swift, functions without return value have an implicit return value of type `Void`.)

Comment: “A return statement occurs in the body of a function or method definition and causes program execution to return to the calling function or method. Program execution continues at the point immediately following the function or method call.”

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2.2).” iBooks. https://itun.es/de/jEUH0.l

Comment: “When a return statement is not followed by an expression, it can be used only to return from a function or method that does not return a value (that is, when the return type of the function or method is Void or ()).”

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 2.2).” iBooks. https://itun.es/de/jEUH0.l

Comment: So functions without return value are in reality functions that return `Void` and when we write `return` in these functions we are in reality returning `Void`

Comment: Yes, but that is just syntactic sugar (as I understand it). On runtime, the function just returns, there is no "Void" value put into a register as return value.

Comment: @MartinR: Are you sure? We may capture the `()` instance just as any instance in a variable (`let foo = nothin()`; however yielding a warning), but perhaps this is a special case triggered when we explicitly want to store the return.

Comment: @dfri: I have inspected the generated assembly code of `@inline(never) func foo() { return () }` with `swiftc -emit-assembly -O main.swift`. I am not an expert in assembly programming, but as far as I can see, no return value is put on the stack or into a return register.

Comment: @MartinR I see, thanks. Interestingly, the `sizeof` the empty tuple is `0`, whereas the `strideof` it is `1` (although `strideof` is strictly positive, so this perhaps doesn't say much). Also, we can create e.g. arrays of empty tuples (as initialized e.g. by return from a function call), which are stored, but that's probably playing with non-intended features. Since type `()` can only hold a single unique value (`()`), maybe there is no need to resolve any captured `()`-returns from functions, as the compiler can deduce the (single unique) return value of these captures at compile time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following signatures all return an *instance* of the empty tuple `()` (typealiased as `Void`).

```
func implicitlyReturnEmptyTuple() { }

func explicitlyReturnEmptyTuple() {
    return ()
}

func explicitlyReturnEmptyTupleAlt() {
    return
}
```

In all of the three above, the return type of the function, in the function signature, has been omitted, in which case it is implicitly set to the empty tuple type, `()`. I.e., the following are analogous to the three above

```
func implicitlyReturnEmptyTuple() -> () { }

func explicitlyReturnEmptyTuple() -> () {
    return ()
}

func explicitlyReturnEmptyTupleAlt() -> () {
    return
}
```

---

With regard to your comment below (regarding body of `implicitlyReturnEmptyTuple()` where we don't explicitly return `()`); from [the Language Guide - Functions: Functions without return values](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html):

> Functions are not required to define a return type. Here’s a version
>   of the `sayHello(_:)` function, called `sayGoodbye(_:)`, which prints
>   its own `String` value rather than returning it:
>
> ```
> func sayGoodbye(personName: String) {
>     print("Goodbye, \(personName)!")
> }
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ***Note***
>
> Strictly speaking, the `sayGoodbye(_:)` function **does still return a
>   value**, even though no return value is defined. Functions **without a
>   defined return type return a special value of type `Void`**. This is
>   simply an empty tuple, in effect a tuple with zero elements, which can
>   be written as `()`.

Hence, we may omit `return ...` only for `()`-return (`Void`-return) function, in which case a `()` *instance* will be returned implicitly.

Comment: that's interesting, I am curious about the first case `func implicitlyReturnEmptyTuple() -> () { }` we did not write `return` and it expect a `return ()` or `return`

Comment: That's what I wanted to understand

Comment: @iOSGeek happy to help. See also [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34561452/) for a small discussion of instances of the empty tuple.

Answer (score 5):

In that case, `return` only means "leave the function".

Comment: yes I know but I wanted to understand how it works,  any further explanation how Swift deal with this case and the case where there is a value

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. At the lowest level, the compiler knows where the calling function expects to find a return value if there's one, and it builds your function to write its return value there. If there isn't, then nothing gets written in that location and the caller doesn't try to read from it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Functions are first class objects in Swift . 
They have a type

```
func nothing(){
    return
}
```

Actual representation of the above function is like this

```
func nothing()->(){
        return
    }
```

In the above code the type of the function is an empty tuple

> "()"

If you assign the above function to some variable , we can see the returned tuple

[image]