# What is return type " () "?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a function, which takes several other functions as arguments:

```
class Iterator {
    func iterateItems(itemArray: [Items], removeItem: (Items) -> Void, addItem: (inout Items) -> Void, calculateEfficiency: () -> Void) -> [Items] {
        // function body
    }
}
```

And I call it in its class' subclass like this:

```
class WPCalculator: Iterator {

    func removeWeaponItem(item: WeaponItems) { ... }
    func addWeaponItem(item: inout WeaponItems) { ... }
    func calcWeaponDamage() { ... }

    func iterateWPItems() {
        return iterateItems(itemArray: WeaponItems.weaponItems, removeItem: removeWeaponItem as! (Items) -> Void, addItem: addWeaponItem as! (inout Items) -> Void, calculateEfficiency: calcWeaponDemage)
   }
}
```

Also the `WeaponItems` class is a subclass of `Items` class:

```
class WeaponItems: Items { ... }
```

Xcode gives me a warning on `addWeaponItem`:

> Cast from `(inout WeaponItems) -> ()` to unrelated type `(inout Items) -> Void` always fails

---

I can't understand the `-> ()` return type, clearly its not what my function does, the other functions passed as arguments without inout parameters just worked fine

Comment: `()` is the same as `Void`. Should be in the Swift book, search for "empty tuple".

Comment: Related: [Return in function without return value in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38946275/) and [Are there any possible explicit uses of instances (values) of empty tuples (), i.e., of instances of typealias 'Void'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34561452/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `iterateItems` has `removeItem` `addItem` `calculateEfficiency`  parameter is function type. So you must use function name as params when call function.

like this:

```
iterateItems(itemArray: WeaponItems.weaponItems, removeItem: removeWeaponItem, addItem: addWeaponItem, calculateEfficiency: calcWeaponDamage)
```

Comment: I think that's what I did, and Xcode asked me to type cast, which strangely failed on `addWeaponItem`

Comment: @BrightFuture I think Swift will not allow to type cast in-out parameters, because you can change this type of param inside your function. Better write a new  addWeaponItem(item: inout Items) function

Answer (score 0):

I think `()` same as `Void`

The warning occurs because `WeaponItems` and `Items` do not match

http://ericasadun.com/2015/05/11/swift-vs-void/