# What is type '()' in swift?

Tags: swift

I'm receiving an event that passes a parameter of type `()`.

Is it an empty tuple..?

I'm referring to this type of expression:

`let x = ()`

Comment: @xoudini: Closely related, but not exactly the same (I think). That question is about  `()` as a type. Here `()` is a value, and cannot be replaced by `Void`. `let x = Void` does not compile.

Comment: Interesting discussion on the explicit uses of `()` as a value here: [Are there any possible explicit uses of instances (values) of empty tuples (), i.e., of instances of typealias 'Void'?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34561452/2976878)

Comment: @MartinR Good point, and on another look I'll have to agree that the questions aren't exactly the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`()` is both a *type* (and `Void` is a type alias for the empty tuple type) and the only *value* of that type. So

```
let x = ()
```

defines `x` as a constant property of *type* `()` (aka `Void`) with the *value* `()`.

Equivalent statements would be

```
let x:() = ()
let x:Void = ()
```

but *not*

```
let x = Void // error: expected member name or constructor call after type name
```

because `Void` is a type but not a value.

When defining *function types* with no parameters and/or no return value
there seems to be a consensus to use `()` for an empty parameter list,
and `Void` for no return value. This can for example be seen in
UIKit completion handlers, or for execution blocks submitted to
GCD dispatch queues, e.g.

```
func sync(execute block: () -> Void)
```

Comment: A would add that the consensus for defining functions with no params and no return value is `() -> Void` although both `() -> ()` and `(Void) -> Void` are possible.

Comment: @Sulthan: You are right and thanks for the suggestion. However, I would prefer to backup that with some reference which I haven't found yet.

Comment: I don't think there is a reference if you don't count Apple reference documentation for all the completion handlers :)

Comment: @Sulthan: Done, thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's the empty tuple, aka `Void`.

The standard `Void` type is defined as:

```
typealias Void = ()
```

> The return type of functions that don’t explicitly specify a return type; an empty tuple (i.e., `()`).

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the docs for the [Swift grammar](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/tuple-type):

> All tuple types contain two or more types, except for `Void` which is a `type alias` for the empty tuple type, `()`.

```
tuple-type → (­)­ | (­ tuple-type-element­ , ­tuple-type-element-list­ )­
tuple-type-element-list → tuple-type-element­ | tuple-type-element ­, ­tuple-type-element-list­
tuple-type-element → element-name­ type-annotation­ | type­
element-name → identifier­
```

Therefore yes, it is a tuple of zero types / elements.

Comment: also from the grammar documentation.

> *All tuple types contain two or more types, except for `Void` which is a type alias for the empty tuple type, `()`*.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella thank you for pointing that sentence out.